# Can three vectors $ v_1,v_2,v_3 \in \mathbb R^2$ may be chosen from ${{ u_1,u_2,u_3,u_4}}$ such that $ u= \sum_{j=1}^{3}s_jv_j $

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

> Let $u_1,u_2,u_3,u_4$ be vectors in $\mathbb{ R^2}$ and
>   $$ u= \sum_{j=1}^{4} t_ju_j;\text{    }t_j>0 \text{ and } \sum_{j=1}^{4} t_j=1$$
>
> Then three vectors $ v_1,v_2,v_3 \in \mathbb{R}^2$ may be chosen from ${{ u_1,u_2,u_3,u_4}}$ such that 
>   $$ u= \sum_{j=1}^{3}s_jv_j ;\text{    } s_j\geq 0 \text{ and } \sum_{j=1}^{3} s_j=1$$

Since $u_1,u_2,u_3,u_4$ are linearly dependent, i can replace $u_4$ (assuming $u_4$ is dependent one) by linear combination of $u_1,u_2,u_3$ so that $ u= \sum_{j=1}^{3}s_jv_j$ but I can't claim $\sum_{j=1}^{3} s_j=1$  .i'm stuck

Please give me a hint! (Using linear algebra )
I didn't studied topology yet, so it's hard for me to understand topological proof!
Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean chosen from or constructed from? Maybe "chosen from the span of.."?

Comment: @Paul chosen from given vectors. And not from span

Comment: Source : part A 6th question.  http://univ.tifr.res.in/gs2019/Files/GS2012_QP_MTH.pdf

Comment: @CloudJR you can't do what you say you can. For example, if $\;u_1=u_2=0\;,\;\;u_3=(1,0)\;,\;\;u_4=(0,1)\;$ , there in $\;u=u_4\;$ you can't dispose of $\;u_4\;$...unless some other conditions are given.

Comment: @DonAntonio, well i actually assume u4 is dependent, let me edit it thanks

Answer (score 2):

By its definition, $u$ lies in the convex hull of the $u_i$. It suffices to show that for any $u$ there are three $u_i$ whose convex hull contains $u$.

- If there are four points on the convex hull, without loss of generality take them to be $u_1u_2u_3u_4$ in that order. Then $u_1u_2u_3$ and $u_3u_4u_1$ partition the hull, so $u$ lies in at least one of them; the points of the enclosing triangle may be taken as the $v_i$.
- If there are only three points on the convex hull, a correct choice of $v_i$ is simply those three points.
- The two- and one-point cases are trivial.

Comment: I didn't studied convex hull before. Your proof looks geometrically intuitive, but it's hard for me to understand

Comment: @CloudJR Perhaps you studied "barycentric coordinates" and stuff, which is just next to convex hulls and etc. ?

Comment: But i will try to understand, and i will comment if i understood or having any problem. Please help ! Thanks

Comment: @DonAntonio nope. I'm not that good at geometry , i  am just a second year undergraduate. I think it was a linear algebra problem, but when i tried no linear algebraic tools works... So i ask help here.I'm gonna check it out , in wiki or some books and let you know if i understood. Thanks

Comment: As far as I remember this is standard 2nd. undergraduate year stuff, and many times it is taught within linear algebra and not until topology...

Comment: @DonAntonio could you suggest me a good place to study that... Book or online resources  or video lectures etc

Comment: @CloudJR The following two papers are heavily geometric: http://zacharyabel.com/papers/Barycentric_A07.pdf , https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/d7be/b4eabd3ea7108ff41135d87984a34c29ce7c.pdf . You can also try following one, with a more remarked algebraic taste: https://www.ljll.math.upmc.fr/ledret/M1English/M1ApproxPDE_Chapter5-2.pdf

Comment: @DonAntonio , you are a nice man, its unfortunate that you stop participate in this site no more